# url_for doing strange things with jquery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I'm currently struggling with python/flask/Jquery!
I want to use the `URL_for` function in a `img` tag, but when using it, the browser makes strange things!

```
$("div.left").append("<img id='my_img' class='centered' style='width:100%; height:100%' src=" + "{{ url_for('static', filename='./img/logo.png') }}" + "alt='Loading error!' />")
```

This is what the browser gives me:

```
<img id="my_img" class="centered" style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/static/img/logo.pngalt='Loading" error!'="">
```

Last question: Is it possible to put the code in a `js` file with the url_for (seems not to work for me!)?

Comment: I think the problem is in use of single quote and double quote. Better keep ```{{ url_for('static', filename='./img/logo.png') }}``` in a separate variable and concatenate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem caused with double and single quotes. Can you please try that;

```
$("div.left").append('<img id="my_img" class="centered" style="width:100%; height:100%" src="{{url_for("static", filename="./img/logo.png")}}" alt="Loading error!" />')
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me! Do you have any idea for my second question?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are trying with Jquery means follow below code

```
$(function() {
  $("div.left").append("<img id='my_img' class='centered' style='width:100%; height:100%' src='" + url_for('static','./img/logo.png')+"' alt='Loading error!' />")
});

function url_for(a,b){
    return b;
}
```